# XSD: Define element dataType based on attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to define XSD for following xml element that have attribute "type" which decide it's data Type.

```html
<kpp:property name = "SUPorganisationId" type = "integer">xxx </kpp:property>
```

Is there any way to define xsd element type based on its attribute?

```html
<xs:element name="SUPorganisationId" type="This type should be defined from the value of TYPE attribute below">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:attribute name="TYPE" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```